# How to store value of Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap in a variable

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm not able to store value of below command in a variable.

For example:

```
$files = Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia" | Select-Object Name

Write-Host "$files"
```

NOTE: I'm getting result if I execute it separately. It'll give me 16 files.

Comment: Just use `$files` and see if the output is there.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: That means the variable is having an error being defined

Comment: But I'm getting result from the GET command Any idea of how to resolve it ?

Comment: Try `$files = $(Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia" | Select-Object Name)`

Comment: @NekoMusume

Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia" | Select-Object Name | forEach  {
$_
}


I'm also trying above command , but the result is 

Output:

@{Name=myfile-json-dev-001}


But I need only file name i.e "myfile-json-dev-001"

Comment: I don't have the `Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap` command installed I think, but try just using `Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap` and put the output in your question.

Comment: @NekoMusume

Ok , No Problem , But can you please tell me how to fetch file name from the below output 


Actual Output:

@{Name=myfile-json-dev-001}


Expected output:

myfile-json-dev-001

Comment: Oh... Try `$(Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia")["name"]` or `$(Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia").name`

Comment: It is a hashtable, you cannot use `select`

Comment: @ParminderSingh, if somebody provided an answer and it can solve your issue, you should accept it as answer as per this [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=active#tab-top). Otherwise, some people don't like to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62235204/how-to-store-value-of-get-azintegrationaccountmap-in-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment110072445_62235204) comment, your output is a hashtable which in turn means that

```
Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia" | Select-Object Name
```

Will do you no good. In hash tables, you take input from the table with

```
$var.value
```

or

```
$var["value"]
```

For example if I make a hash table

```
$test = @{name="test"}
```

I can take input from it like

```
$test.name
```

Output:

```
test
```

and the other way:

```
$test["name"]
```

Output (again):

```
test
```

So try using

```
$files = $(Get-AzIntegrationAccountMap -ResourceGroupName "test-rg" -Name "testing-ia").name

write-host "$files"
```

Comment: Your welcome, happy to help :). If this answered your question please hit the green checkmark on the top left of the my answer to accept it. : )